# Azure ML: how to change the "cluster purpose" of an existing inference cluster from "dev_test" to "production"?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a cluster whose "cluster_purpose" was set to "dev_test". I want to change it to "production". Couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. This is not possible.